# Failed to load resource:404 image

Tags: images, errors, 404-error

website is http://pleevi.com. when i look on the problems with the website, i get this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jXhF.png

here is the entire list of what i get as i cannot post more than 2 hyper links :(

none of the images on my website will load. strange thing is that on my computer the images show up and everything is normal, but when i go to another computer, none of the images show up.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule in your .htaccess that prevents access to your images for anyone sending your domain as referer. Disable the referer on your site, and all images will show up.

Remove that rule.

To get this on topic: Whenever you have any problem where you don’t know how to debug it –disable all plugins, switch to TwentyEleven and use the default .htaccess. Then re-enable each part step by step until the problem comes back.